# How to Display a Plugin function (content) on frontpage using index.php

Tags: plugins, functions, theme-development, theme-customizer, frontpage

Slightly Advanced Noob Alert: {Sorry}.

I'm designing a WordPress Site {No Active Yet}. I have a plugin [feelbox], but currently it displays only on the single post page. There is no option in the plugin settings to display it on the frontpage [index.php]. Here is the main plugin file - feelbox.php is too long to post here. Here is the first part of it:

```
> if (!$options) {
        feelbox_add_default_options();
    } else {
        if ($options['showinpostsondefault'] == 'on') {
            add_filter('the_content', 'add_feelbox_widget_to_posts');
        }
        if (empty($options['showtweetfollowup'])) {
            $temp = array(
                'showtweetfollowup' => 'on'
            );          
            update_option('feelbox_wp_options', $temp);         
        }   
    }
}

function feelbox_add_default_options() {    
    $temp = array(
        'showsparkbar' => 'on',
        'showinpostsondefault' => 'on',
        'showtweetfollowup' => 'on',
        'validkey' => '0',
        'sortmoods' => 'off'
    );

    update_option('feelbox_wp_options', $temp);
}

function feelbox_website_and_apikey_match() {
    $options = get_option('feelbox_wp_options');
    return $options['validkey'] == '1';
}

function feelbox_get_widget_html() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    global $moods;

    if ( ( $use_centralized_site == FALSE ) || ($use_centralized_site == TRUE && feelbox_website_and_apikey_match()) ) {
        $post_id = (int)$post->ID;
        $obj = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lydl_posts WHERE ID=" . $post_id, ARRAY_A);
        $sum = $obj["emotion_1"]+$obj["emotion_2"]+$obj["emotion_3"]+$obj["emotion_4"]+$obj["emotion_5"]+$obj["emotion_6"];
```

But here is my index.php:

```
 <?php $mts_options = get_option('dualshock'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page">
    <div class="content">
        <article class="article">
            <div id="content_box">
                <?php $j = 0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                        <header>                        
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                        </header><!--.header-->
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                                <?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('featured',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                                    <img width="450" height="200" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nothumb.png" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
                            <?php echo excerpt(38);?>
                        </div>

                    </div><!--.post excerpt-->

                    <div class="post-info">

                        <span class="thecomment"><?php echo comments_number(__('No Comment','mythemeshop'), __('One Comment','mythemeshop'), '<span class="comments">'.__('Comments','mythemeshop').'</span> <span class="comm">%</span>');?></span>
                        <span class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _e('Read More','mythemeshop'); ?></a></span>

                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
                <span><?php if ( function_exists('print_feelbox_widget') ) { print_feelbox_widget(); } ?></span>
                <!--Start Pagination-->
                <?php if ( isset($mts_options['mts_pagenavigation']) == '1' ) { ?>
                    <?php  $additional_loop = 0; pagination($additional_loop['max_num_pages']); ?>           
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                            <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <!--End Pagination-->
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried to call up the function by inserting this under the post-info DIV, no luck.

`<?php if ( function_exists('print_feelbox_widget') ) { print_feelbox_widget(); } ?>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin inserts its feelbox widget by filtering `the_content`:

```
if ($options['showinpostsondefault'] == 'on') {
    add_filter('the_content', 'add_feelbox_widget_to_posts');
}
```

But your index page doesn't display the_content, just Title, featured thumbnail, an excerpt and, number of comments.

The plugin code you've shown us doesn't include a `print_feelbox_widget()` function. Does such a function actually exist in your plugin? (Also, you've included it after the closing tag of your post-info div, and outside the close of "the loop" (`<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`) so if it's meant to be used in "the loop" you need to move it up a couple lines.)

Otherwise, you might be able to hack your plugin to filter an additional template tag (`the_excerpt`?) and then add that tag to your `index.php` template.

So, in your plugin:

```
if ($options['showinpostsondefault'] == 'on') {
    add_filter('the_content', 'add_feelbox_widget_to_posts');
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'add_feelbox_widget_to_posts');
}
```

Then, in `index.php` something like:

```
<div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
</div>
```

You'll have to play around with exact placement, of course.

Good luck.

Comment: Hmmm, tried that. This is what I got back at the bottom of the  featured image in the front page.'code' Warning: Missing argument 1 for excerpt(), called in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas07_data03/24/2493124/html/wp-content/themes/dualshock/index.php on line 24 and defined in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas07_data03/24/2493124/html/wp-content/themes/dualshock/functions.php on line 230